# How to point the clickable app name on shared facebook post to my app's website

Tags: facebook, azure, azure-mobile-services, facebook-share, facebook-app-settings

I'm using Azure mobile service backend for my ios app.This app is integrated with Facebook auth.Everything works fine.

I have configured the Facebook app as mentioned in the azure backend docs for authentication.The website site url is shown as below.

[image]

Meanwhile, in my ios appthere's a feature to share an image with Facebook friends. I'm using FBSDKShareDialog.However, when this image is shared it comes up as the below image.In the blacked out area Facebook shows the name of my app and that name is actually a clickable link. That link takes me to the "site url" i gave in the configuration above.

[image]

My question is how can i make this link point to my app's website and NOT the azure service backend address ? I cannot change the website url given above in the configuration, as it'll mess up my configuration.

Really stuck with this.

Answer (score 2):

That "Site URL" entry on the Facebook Settings Basic tab should not be your Mobile Service URL. You can put the public URL for your app's website.

On the Advanced tab, the "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" is the setting where you need to add your Mobile Service URL (or multiple, if you have multiple versions of your app using different Mobile Services): `https://<mobile_service>.azure-mobile.net/login/facebook` for the Javascript backend, or `https://<mobile_service>.azure-mobile.net/signin-facebook` for .NET backends.